# CSS Background: Linear Gradient - Animation is not functioning as Wished to be

Tags: css, background, css-animations, linear-gradients, keyframe

I am facing an issue implementing the animation. The below code snippet is working fine. Currently, the background is animating from left to right only. But I want to reverse the above animation when its cycle ends (reaches the bottom right corner), then the animation should start from there to the left.

> I also tried adding a new animation with a 1.5s delay (when the first
> animation ends) by changing the background position (with javascript),
> but it didn't work.

I've already read all the possible answers but didn't find a useful one. Can anyone assist with a suggestion/alternative approach or point out what I'm doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated..!

```css
.user-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bg-slide 1.5s ease infinite;
  border: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  background: 0 0/300% 300% linear-gradient(-60deg, #eee 40%, #18d26e 50%, #eee 60%);
}

@keyframes bg-slide {
  from {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630208232589-e42b29428b19?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8cHJvZmlsZSUyMHBob3RvfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60" alt="user-image" class="user-img" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `alternate` to your `animation` setting (for the animation-direction):

```css
.user-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bg-slide 1.5s ease infinite alternate;
  border: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  background: 0 0/300% 300% linear-gradient(-60deg, #eee 40%, #18d26e 50%, #eee 60%);
}

@keyframes bg-slide {
  from {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630208232589-e42b29428b19?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8cHJvZmlsZSUyMHBob3RvfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60" alt="user-image" class="user-img" />
```

Comment: I am surprised what I was missing is just an `alternate` keyword. Maybe sometimes my mind does not work as expected . Thanks a lot [@Johannes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5641669/johannes). Answer Accepted ✔

Answer (score 0):

Add `animation-direction: alternate;` in the `.user-img` class.

```css
.user-img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bg-slide 1.5s ease infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  border: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  background: 0 0/300% 300% linear-gradient(-60deg, #eee 40%, #18d26e 50%, #eee 60%);
}

@keyframes bg-slide {
  from {
    background-position: 100% 50%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1630208232589-e42b29428b19?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8OXx8cHJvZmlsZSUyMHBob3RvfGVufDB8fDB8fA%3D%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=400&q=60" alt="user-image" class="user-img" />
```